# Error while set a paragraph field to NULL during cron run

Tags: 8, entities, cron, paragraphs

I am using Drupal 8 and I have implemented a `hook_cron` to set a node field to NULL. Here is my code:

```
if ($lesson->field_lesson_ended_at->value < $current_time && $session_id && count($paragraphs) > 0) {
  $pids = [];
  foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
    $pids[] = $paragraph['target_id'];
  }
  $storage_handler = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('paragraph');
  $entities = $storage_handler->loadByProperties(['id' => $pids]);

  foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    try {
      $apiObj->forceDisconnect($session_id, $entity->get('field_session_connection_id')->value);
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
  }
  $storage_handler->delete($entities);
  $lesson->set("field_session_id", NULL);
  $lesson->save();
}
```

When cron task reaches these lines:

```
$lesson->set("field_session_id", NULL);
$lesson->save();
```

Throws the following error (capture from cron logs):

```
Error: Call to a member function getTranslation() on null in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->hasTranslationChanges() (line 1430 of core\lib\DRupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase.php)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot and a dpm before the exception is thrown an after? Because at first glance theres nothing wrong with your code. Also you can simplify loading the paragraphs by `$storage_handler->loadMultiple($pids)` and seems also that your `$paragraphs ` variable is getted from a field, you can load paragraphs directly an avoid the storage load and the iteration by calling `$paragraphs = $node->get('my_field')->referencedEntities();` this will return the full instance of paragraphs.

Comment: For more information about how paragraphs are loaded directly from the field, see `\Drupal\entity_reference_revisions\EntityReferenceRevisionsFieldItemList::referencedEntities`

Comment: You shouldn't delete paragraphs manually. Remove them from the field and let the module clean up not used paragraphs, they might still be needed for older revisions.

Comment: @4k4 you mean that can`t delete paragraphs programmatically?

Comment: I change line orders like this and it works as needed:
  
  $lesson->set("field_session_id", NULL);
  $lesson->save()
  $storage_handler->delete($entities);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the cron job is working now after you changed the order, you might get the same error later when using the saved parent entity.

Don't delete referenced paragraph entities programmatically (now the last command after you've changed the order). The Entity Reference Revisions module is handling this automatically after all revisions referencing the paragraph are removed.

Comment: Isn't that possible now? Check this https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2741937 is a follow up from this meta https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_revisions/issues/2771531

Comment: I mean "Is possible" typo there

Comment: @d70rr3s, we don't know whether the OP has run into one of those issues, but even if the garbage collection is not working 100%, it's not a good idea to delete paragraphs without checking their usage.

Comment: Totally agreed just asking about current support since was an issue on the past